# Diferença entre funções estáticas e dinâmicas no PHP

Tags: php, desempenho, static

Para mim a diferença entre métodos estáticos e dinâmicos no contexto de orientação a objetos é clara e faz sentido,
porém, o PHP permite que eu use a palavra chave '**static**' na declarações de funções simples e eu nunca dei atenção para
qual seria a diferença em comportamento, desempenho ou vantagem.

Recentemente instalei o plugin Php Inspections na IDE que uso (PHPStorm) e o mesmo passou a indicar que eu deveria
utilizar o '**static**' em funções anônimas que eu utilizava no sistema dizendo que em algumas situações eu poderia ter uma
melhoria em desempenho, porém, o motivo de tal vantagem não está claro para mim.

Eu gostaria de saber em quais casos a utilização do **static** seria vantajosa em questão de desempenho e em quais casos
fazem sentido eu utilizar o mesmo, visto que não consigo pensar em algum caso em que uma função estática seria útil.

Lembrando que **não** estou falando de métodos de classes, e sim, funções simples

Comment: Não desmerecendo a pergunta, mas não faz muito sentido discutir sobre pequenas melhorias de performance no PHP, a linguagem não foi criada pra ser performática...

Comment: @Costamilam nesse caso faz, pois impacta em otimização na utilização de recursos, não em tempo de execução. Sabendo que PHP não se preocupa em economizar recursos da melhor forma, fazê-lo a nível de aplicação pode fazer sentido.